# I just made a welcome and goodbye message for my discord.js bot but it doesn't send the messages to the required channels

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Here's my code,

Welcome message:

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
if(member.guild.id !== "737222740305641472")return;
const channel = guild.channels.cache.get("750952211659620413")
if (!channel) return;

   let data = await canva.welcome(member, { link: "https://imgur.com/a/BPTpkDT", blur: false })

const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(
  data,
  "welcome-image.png"
);

channel.send(
    "Welcome message here",
  attachment
);   
});
```

And my goodbye message's code:

```
client.on('guildMemberRemove',(member) => {
if(member.guild.id !== "737222740305641472")return;
guild.channels.cache.get('781737515421138984').send(`Goodbye message here`);
});
```

I'd like to make it clear that I dont get any error's in my console and that I've given the bot all the perms it needs to send messages.

Also, I've already declared my guild before, so that isn't supposed to be the problem.

Can anyone tell what I'm doin wrong?

Comment: Have you enabled privilliged intents? and what is your discord.js version?

Comment: What are privileged intents? My discord.js version is v12.5.6

Comment: I recon you haven't enables intents then, since you do not know what they are I would post it as an answer.

Comment: Ummmm, sure ig.

Comment: Wait, do I enable it via the discord dev portal?

Edit: I just enabled the Server members intent from the dev portal, lemme try it out

Comment: And It didnt work, is there anything I need to add to my index.js file after enabling privileged intents?

Comment: Nope! consider using `try/catch` in that case! maybe your bot is lacking permissions in the VERY SPECIFIC CHANNEL, everything would be appearent with a single line of code add this: ```channel.send(
    "Welcome message here",
  attachment
).catch((e) => console.error(e))
```

Answer (score 1):

As directed by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69171849/i-just-made-a-welcome-and-goodbye-message-for-my-discord-js-bot-but-it-doesnt-s?noredirect=1#comment122257076_69171849), it is appearent that you have not enabled privilliged intents for your application. For your application to listen to events such as `guildMemberAdd` and `guildMemberRemove` you would have to enable to `Members Intent` from the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers). Here is what you would be looking for:

[image: Intents]

This can be found under
**Your Application > Bot >** ( Scroll down ) **Privilleged Gateway Intents > Server Members Intent** ( toggleable ).

 
This was a change introduced in the [Discord API version v8](https://discord.com/api/v8)  for the intents to be mandatorily enabled for such API requests.

Comment: I just enabled it, it still doesnt work...
Edit: I'm tryin it again

Comment: THANKS A ZILLION DUDE, IT FINALLY WORKSSSS!!
You're awesome!

Comment: No issues! Make sure to accept the answer with the ✓ button and upvote it with the  button if it helps